# access sql query logs from audit file

Tags: sql-server

In standart edition there is a file which has some info about sql queries logs . and i can access these info with running this query

```
SELECT * FROM fn_get_audit_file('C:\Audit\PCI_Audit*', default, default)
```

this is file name

```
PCI_Audit_EC556E8F-04F0-4E7F-B29E-4856C72ECAEE_0_131108208217630000.sqlaudit
```

and you can download it from [here](https://mega.nz/#!l0Rj1AZb!m60XR3FmzNfXCuI5ESPadpJ7-hnp5g4Mm_5jqicdFwQ).

What ever i did i could not read this file and access info.
any suggestion will help too much

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

There's an SSIS package available that we used once to consolidate the audit logs for many servers into one central repo. Or one can use powershell to manipulate them. Check out two possible solutions below. But we never were able to read the file directly from the OS.

http://sqlcat.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=sqlauditcentral&referringTitle=Home

or

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3444/automate-the-import-of-sql-server-audit-files-into-sql-server-using-powershell/